# ruby sinatra, postgres paging results

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra, sequel

I want to page a dataset.

The Ruby code is:

```
get '/candy' do
    @pagedata = { :cur_page => 1, :post_count => 0, :per_page => 3 }
    # set the current page to show
    @pagedata[:cur_page] = params[:page].to_i unless params[:page].nil?
    @cands = DB[:candidates] 
    #@cands = Post.by_created_at
    # set post_count
    @pagedata[:post_count] = DB[:candidates].count(:id)
    @cands = @cands.paginate(:page => @pagedata[:cur_page], :per_page => @pagedata[:per_page]) unless @cands.empty?
        erb :candy
    end
```

What's the problem? All help gratefully received!

The line:

```
@cands = @cands.paginate(:page => @pagedata[:cur_page], :per_page => @pagedata[:per_page]) unless @cands.empty?
```

Produces the error:

```
undefined method `paginate' for Sequel::Postgres::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM "candidates"
```

Comment: sorry, I have made a mess of this. I am writing the code again and I will repost if I get stuck, which I expect to do.

Comment: OK Nicholas, I have updated and given the information you requested. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `DB.extension(:pagination)` after creating your `DB` object.

Comment: thanks Jeremy, now I am getting: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Comment: OK, fixed it! Where can I find out what goes in the view to make the paging work?! Sorry ....